# C# regexp \w with +, * doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: c#, regex

I've got such a piece of code:

```
String source = "There will will be";
Regex r = new Regex(@"There \w+ be");
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(source).Value);
```

And I can't see anything in the output, if the source is There will be, I can see the output. Could anyone explain it to me?

And some extent to a question. How to create a Regex that will find between 1 or 2 (that's an example, I'm writing some kind of parser and need to create my own wildchar that behaves that way) words. I've already tried a few combinations but everything fails. 
One of my tries:

```
@"\w+\s{1,2}"
```

I think it's wrong becouse {1,2} tells that regexp to repeat whitespace 1 or 2 times, not whole \w+\s. Do you know how to fix it or make in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the fact that this code won't match. `\w` can be any alphanumerical character and the underscore (so essentially `A` through `Z`, `0` through `9` and `_`). Spaces however are their own group (represented by `\s`).

To fix this, you can make the regular expression match both by creating a group where the matching algorithm can pick any element using `[]`:

`There [\w\s]+? be`

Note that I also added a `?` to make this a non-greedy match, trying to match a small as possible part of the text (otherwise you could just skip a `be` while matching).

---

As for the addition, just use a non-matching group (saving some processing time and memory compared to a matching group):

`(?:\w+\s){1,2}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please help me one more time with some extension to a question?

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches any word character(a-zA-Z0-9 and underscore). `There will will be` would require `\w+` to match `will will`. `\w` can't match the space, thus the regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

That's because space is not matched within `\w+`. Try using either of the following:

```
@"There \w+ \w+ be"
```

or

```
@"There [\w\s]+ be"
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches all alphanumeric characters and the underscore. In your example it would have to match `will will` which contains a space and therefore does not match. Your expression will however match `There will be` with only one `will`.

Answer (score 0):

\w matches word characters, so the space between the two 'will' strings prevents the match.  You might want to replace it with `@"There \w+(?:\s+\w+)* be"` instead.